# How to convert a JSON file into a dictionnary with Python 3

Tags: python, json, list

first post here. Total newbie in Python & programming in general.

Basically I'm following this guy's [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4wdm488mkE&t=30s)(not querying the same API though) **about extracting data from a JSON response in Python**.

Here is my (very simple) code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
import requests

url = 'http://calendar.voyages-sncf.com/cdp/api/proposals/v3/outward/FRPAR/FRGNL/2017-11-01/12-HAPPY_CARD/2/fr/fr?fareCodes=HC16&onlyDirectTrains=true'

json_data = requests.get(url).json()
json_segments = json_data['segments'] 

print (json_segments)
```

Now, instead of extracting the data marked with 'Segments' in the JSON file. I get this error:

```
json_segments = json_data['status']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

So, I've tried int(), to make it an integer but does not work.

Thank you very much if you can help.

Comment: `json_data` is a `list`, not a `dict`. To get the, say, first item out of a list, use `json_data[0]`

Comment: Json format doesn't mean you magically get a dictionary. You have a list apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data returned by `requests.get().json()` is a list of data. You can iterate through the list by using a `for data in json_data:` loop. Then you can access the 'segments' key of the dict directly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests

url = 'http://calendar.voyages-sncf.com/cdp/api/proposals/v3/outward/FRPAR/FRGNL/2017-11-01/12-HAPPY_CARD/2/fr/fr?fareCodes=HC16&onlyDirectTrains=true'

json_data = requests.get(url).json()

for data in json_data:
    print(data['segments'])
```

Regarding your question about the tutorial code:

```
import urllib.parse

import requests

address = 'lhr'
main_api = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'
url = main_api + urllib.parse.urlencode({'address': address})
json_data = requests.get(url).json()
json_status = json_data['status']
print(json_status)
```

The docs for the [google geocoding api here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) (the api he is using in the video) specify that you will get a dictionary with the a specific architecture. However when you are getting your data from `http://calendar.voyages-sncf.com/cdp/api` they are not returning the same data structure. In their case it is a list of dictionaries.

So every time you get new data from a different api (or a different endpoint in the same api) you will get data in a different structure. Therefor you will need to change your code to work with each piece of data.

JSON is simply a standard way to change a dictionary, list, or other native (native to python, java, or what ever language you are using at the time) to and from a string after it is sent over a network. This can lead to problems. Specifically in python a `set()` can not be changed directly to JSON. It needs to be changed to a list then to JSON, then back to a list then back to a set on the other side.

The following example is was copied from the google docs [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) with minor modifications to make it smaller and more readable.

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.4224764,
               "lng" : -122.0842499
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4238253802915,
                  "lng" : -122.0829009197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4211274197085,
                  "lng" : -122.0855988802915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: Whoops. assumed it was just one list. retracted my answer. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. Yet I don't understand how, in the tutorial I watch, he gets a dictionnary directly. Here is his code:            main_api= 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'

url = main_api + urllib.parse.urlencode({'address': address})

json_data = requests.get(url).json()

json_status = json_data['status']

Print(json_status)

Comment: Are you using python 3 or python 2?

Comment: Added an explanation to your question in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO and glad u chose Python :).

If you are new to Python and intend to work with tables do not hesitate to learn **pandas**. There are tons of documents and questions about pandas.

Examples:

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'http://calendar.voyages-sncf.com/cdp/api/proposals/v3/outward/FRPAR/FRGNL/2017-11-01/12-HAPPY_CARD/2/fr/fr?fareCodes=HC16&onlyDirectTrains=true'
df = pd.read_json(url)
```

And

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
df = pd.concat(json_normalize(df["segments"].values[i]) for i in range(len(df)))
```

With pandas you can output to list, dictionaries, csv, json and so on...

Here is a snippet that returns html table with first 3 rows:

```
print(df.head(3).to_html(index=False))
```

Result

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>arrivalDate</th>
      <th>carrierCode</th>
      <th>departureDate</th>
      <th>destination.cityLabel</th>
      <th>destination.label</th>
      <th>destination.rrcode</th>
      <th>duration</th>
      <th>inventory</th>
      <th>onboardServices</th>
      <th>origin.cityLabel</th>
      <th>origin.label</th>
      <th>origin.rrcode</th>
      <th>physicalSpace</th>
      <th>quotations.12-HAPPY_CARD.cos</th>
      <th>quotations.12-HAPPY_CARD.cosLevel</th>
      <th>quotations.12-HAPPY_CARD.fareCode</th>
      <th>quotations.12-HAPPY_CARD.fareCondition.conditions</th>
      <th>quotations.12-HAPPY_CARD.fareCondition.fareName</th>
      <th>quotations.12-HAPPY_CARD.fareSequence</th>
      <th>quotations.12-HAPPY_CARD.fareSpecificRule</th>
      <th>quotations.12-HAPPY_CARD.passengerType</th>
      <th>trainNumber</th>
      <th>trainType</th>
      <th>transporter</th>
      <th>travelClass</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2017-11-01T19:46</td>
      <td>SN</td>
      <td>2017-11-01T16:41</td>
      <td>Grenoble</td>
      <td>Grenoble</td>
      <td>FRGNB</td>
      <td>185</td>
      <td>wdi</td>
      <td>[BAR, HAN, SMP]</td>
      <td>Paris</td>
      <td>Paris Gare de Lyon</td>
      <td>FRPLY</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>BN</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>HC16</td>
      <td>[Pièce d'identité à présenter à bord du train....</td>
      <td>TGVmax</td>
      <td>None</td>
      <td>None</td>
      <td>PT00AD</td>
      <td>6921</td>
      <td>TGD</td>
      <td>tgv</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2017-11-01T17:45</td>
      <td>SN</td>
      <td>2017-11-01T14:41</td>
      <td>Grenoble</td>
      <td>Grenoble</td>
      <td>FRGNB</td>
      <td>184</td>
      <td>wdi</td>
      <td>[BAR, HAN, SMP]</td>
      <td>Paris</td>
      <td>Paris Gare de Lyon</td>
      <td>FRPLY</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>BN</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>HC16</td>
      <td>[Pièce d'identité à présenter à bord du train....</td>
      <td>TGVmax</td>
      <td>None</td>
      <td>None</td>
      <td>PT00AD</td>
      <td>6919</td>
      <td>TGD</td>
      <td>tgv</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2017-11-01T10:44</td>
      <td>SN</td>
      <td>2017-11-01T07:41</td>
      <td>Grenoble</td>
      <td>Grenoble</td>
      <td>FRGNB</td>
      <td>183</td>
      <td>wdi</td>
      <td>[VEP, BAR, HAN, SMP]</td>
      <td>Paris</td>
      <td>Paris Gare de Lyon</td>
      <td>FRPLY</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>BN</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>HC16</td>
      <td>[Pièce d'identité à présenter à bord du train....</td>
      <td>TGVmax</td>
      <td>None</td>
      <td>None</td>
      <td>PT00AD</td>
      <td>6905</td>
      <td>TGS</td>
      <td>tgv</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Would you have a book or specific ressource to learn more about pandas ?

Comment: @FreshWhisky You can have a look here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html. Trust me: It is worth your time.